# Preload animation in JavaFX 2.0

Tags: performance, animation, javafx-2

My Problem: I have a complex GridPane. I want to make an overview-scene with nine of these GridPanes. On mouseclick they should scale over the hole scene. So far I had no problem, but when I click on an GridPane it doest about 2 sec nothing and than it it scaled. When I have done this about 10 times it does the animation more or less fluid smooth.
I tried to convert the GridPanes in Images with this: http://blog.ngopal.com.np/2011/10/26/save-node-to-image-in-javafx-2-0/. The Problem is, that in my case this solution is not working.
So is there a possibility to make the GridPane to an image OR preload the animation, so that it is smooth animated on the first cilck?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by reducing the complexity of the GridPane. (I use Images instead of an overlayeffect)